# Read csv en pandas no me muestra todos los valores

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Estoy trabajando con un archivo CSV que baje desde una URL. Lo guarde y hasta ahi esta todo perfecto. Una vez que quiero leerlo e imprimir los resultados solo me muestra algunos. Me pone unos ... ... ...  y me dice cuantos renglones tengo pero no me muestra todos:

```
Sitio                  valores1      valores2  Fill Rate
si.com                  326014         3585      1.10
elcte.com               11333          121       1.07
youthage.co.za          19774          212       1.07
ginh.tv                 44086          457       1.04
taianhdep.com           14149          147       1.04
...                       ...          ...        ...
boe.com.br              411299         868       0.21
jbsis.com               18436          38        0.21
rqueamo.com.br          17414          36        0.21
tats.com                13192          28        0.21
ho.vn                   264321         558       0.21
nie.com.au              126480         264       0.21
[475 rows x 3 columns]
```

Les dejo el codigo aca para que vean:

```
import pandas as pd

datos = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
auto = (datos.sort_values(by='Fill Rate', ascending=False))
auto2 = auto[(auto['Fill Rate'] >0.2)]

f = open("WL.csv", "w")
content2 = str(auto2)

f.write(content2)

f.close()
```

En el codigo lo que hago es leer el csv, ordenarlo por la ultima columna y solo mostrar los valores mas altos de 0.2. Uso Python 2.7

Desde ya, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema básico que tienes es que estás salvando la "versión de pantalla" del dataframe, que está limitado a mostrarte una cantidad de filas como máximo, eventualmente podrías modificarlo por ejemplo así: `pd.set_option('max_rows', 10000)`. Pero más allá de esto, lo correcto sería usar la función propia de pandas para salvar los datos a un csv -> [`to_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). Algo así:

```
df.to_csv("WL.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

Deberías entonces salvar tu `dataframe` de la siguiente forma:

```
import pandas as pd

datos = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
auto = (datos.sort_values(by='Fill Rate', ascending=False))
auto2 = auto[(auto['Fill Rate'] >0.2)]

df.to_csv("WL.csv", sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Me podrias ayudar colocandome alguna de las dos opciones en mi codigo? Soy nuevo y no entiendo mucho como hacerlo. Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: @MartinBouhier, ahí edite la pregunta dejandote el código tal cual debiera ser. Saludos.

Comment: Me fue de gran ayuda! Gracias